# What do return statements do in an AspectJ advice?

Tags: aspectj

The following is an excerpt from an AspectJ [example](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-interType.html#example-pointassertions):

```
class Point  {
      int x, y;

      public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
      // ...
  }

  aspect PointAssertions {

      private boolean Point.assertX(int x) {
          return (x <= 100 && x >= 0);
      }
      // ...

      before(Point p, int x): target(p) && args(x) && call(void setX(int)) {
          if (!p.assertX(x)) {
              System.out.println("Illegal value for x"); return;
          }
      }
      // ...
  }
```

Could someone please clarify for me what the `return;` statement does in the `before` advice - why it is (needs to be?) there and what would happen without it?

Will it basically "return form `setX()`" before the method body is executed?

Is there a manual page explaining it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the answer by @LajosArpad, `before` advices can only change the flow by throwing an exception. The only advice that can prevent calling the advised method while retaining the same flow semantics is `around`, but it needs to return something itself in that case (if the return type is not `void`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks this:

```
(!p.assertX(x))
```

whenever the logical expression above is true, the code in its block of `{ }` will be executed, including the `return;`. The point of the `return` statement is to make sure that the function stops and no further code will be executed. It is a common approach to do so in case of errors.

Comment: By "function", do you mean the `before` advice or the `setX()` method? Because, if it's the former, I'd argue that's pointless with the current code - there are no more statements after the `return;`. And from what I understand from the docs, this wouldn't "terminate" execution of `setX()` (as `before` advice is run in addition of, and not instead of, the actual method), would it?

Comment: Christian, the return we are talking about is in the before function, so it terminates it. Your point about return being pointless in the current code is valid and the return seems to be pointless indeed. My answer was meant to describe the role of the return keyword in general. If we apply it to this particular case, then there is no point indeed to end the function at the end of the function :)